# File upload problem. In what form to send data to API

Tags: java, spring-boot, multipartform-data

Prompt, I have a problem uploading files to the database. I need to implement a controller that accepts a number of files from 1 to n with additional parameters.
For example:

```
public class FilesDTO{
  private String name;


    private String type;

    private MultipartFile file;

get / get 
}
```

further implement the controller, for example:

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "file/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
            MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE })
    public ResponseEntity<?> addFile(@PathVariable Long id, @ModelAttribute List<FilesDTO> filesRequestList) throws IOException {

      // log..

    }
```

how to send a request correctly and in what form to this controller?

If you use postman.
maybe I misunderstood how to implement the controller, tell me how best to do
maybe this should be done not through dto

Answer (score 0):

Use array of multipartfile (you can try to use list instead) and send files by form-data

```
@RequestMapping(value = "file/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<?> addFile(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody MultipartFile[] filesRequestList) throws IOException {

  // log..

}
```

Comment: and how to add any type to each of the file array? For example, what is this video or document or photo?

Comment: you can use getContentType function of MultipartFile class or extract it from file's extension

Comment: and if these are your own designations? not the file format, but its designation, for example, not a photo, but a report, in order to combine them with files MultipartFile